# Play music through Sonos and Google Home at same time?

Tags: smart-home, google-home, google-assistant

Is it possible to play music through both my Sonos speakers and Google Home at the same time?

I have successfully set up Google Assistant on my Sonos and connected everything to the Google Home app, but can't seem to use all speakers at once. Perhaps this is just not possible but haven't been able to find any information on the topic.

Comment: A previous poster is correct. The way to do it is by connecting a Sonos speaker to your TV through HDMI. You will need the TV to also have either a Chromecast or a Chromecast with Android TV. Put the Chromecast in a speaker group with your other Google Home speakers. If the TV is on and set to the Chromecast output, the Sonos speaker will play in sync with the other Google Home speakers. I have two of the IKEA Sonos speakers paired together and linked to my Sonos beam. All three Sonos speakers play with my Google Home speakers when arranged this way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a speaker group (assuming the Sonos devices "look" like normal audio cast devices to the infrastructure).

tap the `+` icon in the Google Home app and about 3rd from the top there should be "Create Speaker Group".

Once done you should see the group in the list of cast targets or you can say things like "OK Google, play  on everywhere"

where `everywhere` is the name of the speaker group.

Comment: The Sonos speakers are not available to add to a speaker group, though I'm assuming this must be the way to do it and it is just not available with the Sonos (yet, hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done With a little untraditional work-around. I got a chromecast connected to my TV and a SONOS Beam connected to the TV with a HDMI cable to one of the TVs HDMI ARC ports. I got to one gen 2 speakers paired with my beam. In my bedroom, kitchen and bathroom I got Google home speakers. For this to work the TV must be turned on though… in the google home app you then create a group with your TV(chromecast) and your Google speakers. That’s it. You now have music playing through (in my case) a beam, 2 one gen 2 and all my google speakers at the same time. You can adjust sync between the speakers through the app, if need be. By default it is set at 76 ms. Cheers from Denmark.